# Triggering a NotifyIcon from a ScheduledJob in powershell

Tags: powershell

Consider the following function:

```
function Notify-Windows(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$text, 
    [string]$icon="Info",
    [string]$title )
{
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

    $objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
    $objNotifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = $icon
    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = $text
    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = $title
    $objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True
    $objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
}
```

On its own, this function works as expected, but as soon as I throw it into a scheduled job, it will not notify me:

```
$repeatEvery = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 60
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RepeatIndefinitely -RepetitionInterval $repeatEvery
$options = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
$msg = "Enter the username and password that will run the task";
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Task username and password",$msg,"$env:userdomain\$env:username",$env:userdomain)

Register-ScheduledJob -Name notifyWindows -ScriptBlock {
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
    $objNotifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info"
    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "It worked!"
    $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "My Title"
    $objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True
    $objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)

    Write-Output "The notify-windows function was called and exited properly"
} `
-Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $options -Credential $credential
```

From that code we get the following output:

```
Id         Name            JobTriggers     Command                                  Enabled
--         ----            -----------     -------                                  -------
120        notifyWindows   1               ...                                      True
```

Now we grab the job that we care about and run it:

```
$sch = Get-ScheduledJob -Id 120
$sch.Run()
```

Works:

[image]

But let's now wait for the schedule to kick in.  Then we will grab the job and analyze it:

```
> Get-Job | where { $_.Name -eq "notifyWindows" }

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
161    notifyWindows   PSScheduledJob  Completed     True            localhost            ...    

> $job = Get-Job -Id 161
> $job.Output
The notify-windows function was called and exited properly

> $job.Error.Count
0
```

But still... no notification...

I realize that the scheduled job is running on a separate windows session, but isn't there any way to force it to notify me?  Or maybe all users?

Comment: If I had to guess, the scheduledjob is doing some form of emulation.  I've had bad luck trying to use scheduledjobs over tasks.

Comment: I thought the same thing.  So I did `$sch.RunAsTask()` with no luck either.  I even tried doing it all in task scheduler, no luck.

Comment: Can you set it up to point at a script file in task scheduler (or `-EncodedCommand`) to run at user login?

Comment: Actually while the code above is just a demo, my original code was to be fired at login, and in fact does point to a file, but didn't work either.  I put my code in a ScriptBlock above to make it easier to follow.  With that said, I'm liking your thought process.  Makes me feel like I'm not going crazy for trying all the different things I did until 3:30 AM

Comment: It worked until I changed which user the task runs as.  You may need to create a separate process that determines the logging-in user and start a process as them to see it pop up somehow.

Comment: You mean to say that you got it to work on a schedule that is logged in as a certain user?  I have the job logged in as me, and still haven't seen it notify me on a schedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after much googling unfortunately I have not found a way to make this work with `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon`.  With that said, I DID find a nice little package called [BurntToast](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast) which worked beautifully.

To install:

```
> Install-Module -Name BurntToast
```

and then the updated implementation is as follows:

```
$repeatEvery = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 60
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).Date -RepeatIndefinitely -RepetitionInterval $repeatEvery
$options = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
$msg = "Enter the username and password that will run the task";
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Task username and password",$msg,"$env:userdomain\$env:username",$env:userdomain)

Register-ScheduledJob -Name notifyWindows -ScriptBlock {
    New-BurntToastNotification -Text "It worked!"
    Write-Output "The notify-windows function was called and exited properly"
} `
-Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $options -Credential $credential
```

That's it.  Runs on a schedule of 1 minute, super simple, OSS ftw.  Now I can write jobs that monitor things and alert me when other things happen!  Though it'd still be nice to find out why my other approach didn't work or at least how to make it work.